# What is the `.modules` attribute in python and why does it only exist in some modules, like sys, and not others?

Tags: python, subclass, python-module, sys, python-os

For example, if I import sys and os:

- sys is listed as `<module 'sys' (built-in)>`
- os is listed as `<module 'os' from '/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py'>`

I assumed that meant only "built-in" modules had a `.module` variable, but it turns out the `_abc` built-in doesn't have that.

What I'm mainly interested in is:

1. Why is `.modules` only in some modules
2. Why is `os` listed as a module *inside* of `sys`

   a. I assume this might be because sys uses os internally, but I'm not sure

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules

Comment: `.modules` only exists in `sys` and `sys.modules` is a list of all the modules that are loaded by a process.

Comment: There is **only** `sys.modules`, and it has *nothing to do with* making the `sys` module work. The way to understand what `sys.modules` is for is to [*read the documentation*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules).

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592, and note that this is *not a discussion forum*. Also, we say that `.module` is an *attribute* of `sys`.